# How to change ng-grid foot language

Tags: ng-grid

I am using ng-grid for my web site table Plug-in and 
I want to change "items per page" into another language

How to do this? Can any body help me about this?

I've try the code below but no user:

```
 $scope.gridOptions = {
 i18n: function ($scope, i18nService) {
            i18nService.setCurrentLang('zh-cn');
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

$scope.gridOptions = {
 i18n: "es" // assign language code here
}